# Using Break By for Multiple Fields

Tags: break, progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

I would like to ask how to use multiple break by in a `for each` statement.

Sample:

```
Car Code   Color Code
0001       002
0001       002
0001       001
0005       003
0005       002
0007       001
0008       001
0008       005
0008       001
```

My code is:

```
def var ctr as int.
```

For each car no-lock break by carcode by colorcode.

```
   ctr = ctr + 1.


/*I tried*/
   if last-of(carcode) and last-of(colorcode) then do:
      disp carcode colorcode ctr.
      ctr = 0.
   end. 


/*and tried*/
   last-of(colorcode) then do:
      if last-of(carcode) 
         disp carcode colorcode ctr.
         ctr = 0.
      end.
   end. 
end.
```

My expected output would be:

```
car code   Color Code    QTY
0001       001           1
0001       002           2
0005       002           1
0005       003           1
0007       001           1
0008       001           2
0008       005           1
```

Comment: What language are you talking about? SQL? Also, the question is not very clear. Do you want to count the rows with the same Car Code and Color Code?

Comment: i am using progress 4gl / openedge sorry for not clarifying. What i want is to display the total quantity of the car code with its corresponding color..

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
FOR EACH tablename NO-LOCK 
   BREAK BY carcode 
         BY colorcode: 

   ctr = ctr + 1.

   if last-of(carcode) OR last-of(colorcode) then do:
      disp carcode colorcode ctr.
      ctr = 0.
   end. 
END.
```

It is possible for LAST-OF(colorcode) to be true and LAST-OF(carcode) be false, so change the AND to an OR.

If LAST-OF(carcode) is true, then LAST-OF(colorcode) will also be true.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not work. it had a different output though.

Answer (score 0):

as I was checking on the code, i disregard the use of the last-of and used a temp-table and buffer instead.

```
def buffer btt-car for tt-car.

find first tt-car where tt-car.carcode = car.carcode exclusive.
if not avail tt-car then do:
  create tt-car.
  assign tt-car.car-code = car.carcode
  tt-car.color-code = car.colorcode
  tt-car.qty = tt-car.qty + car.qty.
end.
if avail tt-car then do:
  find first btt-car where btt-car.colorcode = car.colorcode exclusive.
  if not avail btt-car then do:
    create btt-car.
    assign btt-car.car-code = car.carcode
    btt-car.color-code = car.colorcode
    btt-car.qty = btt-car.qty + car.qty.
  end.
  if avail btt-car then assign btt-car.qty = btt-car.qty + car.qty.
end.
```

but if you guys have solutions with using last-of from break by, please share..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
for each car 
    no-lock
    break by car.carcode
          by car.colorcode
:

    accumulate car.colorcode (count by car.colorcode).

    if last-of(car.colorcode)
    then
        display car.carcode 
                car.colorcode
                (accum count by car.colorcode car.colorcode).

end.
```

You can use a variable instead of ACCUMULATE if you want, of course.